# Как создать отдельный task для интеграционного теста в gradle-проекте с несколькими модулями

Tags: gradle, test-automation, модули

Есть проект из нескольких модулей. В gradle для каждого модуля есть раздел project c зависимостями, плагинами и т.д.
Мне нужно для одного из проектов сделать отдельный таск на интеграционный тест.
Проблема в том, что main.path почему-то ссылается на соседний проект, даже если я вызываю его внутри блока project. В sourceSets пути захардкодил

```
sourceSets {
    itest {
        compileClasspath += project.output + test.output
        runtimeClasspath += project.output + test.output
        groovy.srcDir file('../myModule/src/integration-test/groovy')
        resources.srcDir file('../myModule/src/integration-test/resources')
    }
```

Прописал вот такую конфигурацию

```
configurations {
    itestCompile.extendsFrom testCompile
    itestRuntime.extendsFrom testRuntime
}
```

И вот такой таск

```
task itest(type: Test) {
    testClassesDirs = project.sourceSets.itest.output.classesDirs
    classpath = project.sourceSets.itest.runtimeClasspath
}
```

И тест вроде запускается, но не может найти classpath.
Как я понял, проблема в строке runtimeClasspath += project.output + test.output
Пытался её переопределить через files(""), но почему-то не выходит.
Не пойму, какую папку мне туда кидать. Да и плохое это решение - пути хардкодить. sourceSets ни в одном из проектов не назначен отдельно. Не пойму, как это править. Как минимум, чтобы работало, а желательно избавиться от постоянного ручного написания путей, так как такие же таски возможно на другие модули будут.

Answer (score 0):

Как оказалось, были неверно прописаны пути. В итоговом варианте для моего случая пришлось передвинуть sourceSets выше dependencies, а так же добавить туда пару строчек. В итоге заработало в таком виде:

```
sourceSets {
    itest {
        groovy {
            compileClasspath += main.output + test.output
            runtimeClasspath += main.output + test.output
            compileClasspath += project.configurations.testCompileClasspath
            runtimeClasspath += project.configurations.testRuntimeClasspath
            srcDir file('src/itest/groovy')
        }
        resources.srcDir file('src/itest/resources')
    }
}
```